# Converting Function to class Error ('theme' is not defined no-undef)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new in react, I used [material-UI Persistent drawer](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/) in my project, and now I want to change the function for the drawer to class, My problem is the class doesn't recognize the theme this is my code

```
#import .....
const useStyles = theme => ({
root: {
display: 'flex',
},
appBar: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
}),
 //........ there is more of them
}
class Test extends React.Component{
constructor(){
  super()
  this.state={
    open: true,
  }
}
render(){ 
   const { classes } = this.props;
    return(
       <IconButton onClick={this.handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ChevronLeftIcon /> : <ChevronRightIcon />}
       </IconButton>
   );}
}
```

export default Test;
my problem is [ 'theme' is not defined  no-undef ] in the `theme.direction === 'rtl'`

- [this is the code on sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-eyu3f?file=/Hello.js)

Comment: You don't have `theme` defined on your code, what do you expect when you do `theme.direction`?

Comment: @bertdida how should I  define the theme?

Comment: Import `useTheme` from `@material-ui/core/styles` and on the first line of your render method try `const theme = useTheme();`. If it doesn't work, please include a codesandbox.

Comment: @bertdida I added sandbox link tnx

Comment: Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/small-fast-2ylsl?file=/index.js) out.

Comment: If you look at the [Theme Documentation](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#accessing-the-theme-in-a-component) there is a HOC (`withTheme`) that you can use to provide theme to your component instead of having to pass the component theme everywhere it is used.

Comment: @JacobSmit tnx man